# Uninstalled everything I can find, but still extension host terminated unexpectedly

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have been dealing with this issue for a couple of months, but still, I have not fixed it. 
I tried some solutions that I found other posts like, disabling live server, deleting the live server extension file in extension folder and delete code folder in Roaming folder. 
nothing worked. 
so finally I uninstalled vscode. 
after uninstalling it, it works for the first time, but when I close it once and re-launch vscode, the message saying extension host terminated pops up.
[extension host terminated unexpectedly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6V5F.png)

can somebody give me an absolute solution in a way that beginners can understand? 
By looking at the error message, I assume that I have a problem with the folder, but no idea what to do.
Thanks a lot in advance.
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UWGi.png)

Comment: Me Too! This is the latest of the unanswerable questions about 'Why can't I just do what I need with VS Code?